# Deselect Not working In This Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Don't know why deselect is not working.

```
select top 20 * from (
    Select  Rec_Num, 
    COALESCE(AppByENo6,AppByENo5,AppByENo4,AppByENo3,AppByENo2,AppByENo1)
    as 'ApprovedBy' FROM FO_Entry INNER JOIN Employees ON FO_Entry.Hq_Code = Employees.E_HQCode)  as abc
where ApprovedBy LIKE '%2459%'
deselect
select top 10 * from (
    Select  Rec_Num, 
    COALESCE(AppByENo6,AppByENo5,AppByENo4,AppByENo3,AppByENo2,AppByENo1)
    as 'ApprovedBy' FROM FO_Entry INNER JOIN Employees ON FO_Entry.Hq_Code = Employees.E_HQCode)  as abc
where ApprovedBy LIKE '%2459%'
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**The below one is working...  But not the above one...**

```
select top 20 Rec_Num,E_No,E_Name FROM EmployeeDB
except
select top 10 Rec_Num,E_No,E_Name FROM EmployeeDB
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (MS SQL Server?)

Comment: What is "deselect"?  I don't recognize it.

Comment: SQL Server Only

Comment: use `EXCEPT ` In place of deselect

Comment: Simply do a SELECT and put `OFFSET 10 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Query

```
select top 20 * from (
    Select  Rec_Num, 
    COALESCE(AppByENo6,AppByENo5,AppByENo4,AppByENo3,AppByENo2,AppByENo1)
    as 'ApprovedBy' FROM FO_Entry INNER JOIN Employees ON FO_Entry.Hq_Code = Employees.E_HQCode)  as abc
where ApprovedBy LIKE '%2459%'
EXCEPT 
select top 10 * from (
    Select  Rec_Num, 
    COALESCE(AppByENo6,AppByENo5,AppByENo4,AppByENo3,AppByENo2,AppByENo1)
    as 'ApprovedBy' FROM FO_Entry INNER JOIN Employees ON FO_Entry.Hq_Code = Employees.E_HQCode)  as abc
where ApprovedBy LIKE '%2459%'
```

**OR USING OFFSET you can SELECT next 10 rows as below**

```
select * from (
        Select  Rec_Num, 
        COALESCE(AppByENo6,AppByENo5,AppByENo4,AppByENo3,AppByENo2,AppByENo1)
        as 'ApprovedBy' FROM FO_Entry INNER JOIN Employees ON FO_Entry.Hq_Code = Employees.E_HQCode)  as abc
    where ApprovedBy LIKE '%2459%' OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

**OR You can use row_number to SELECT next 10 rows as below**

```
select * from (
    Select  Rec_Num, 
    COALESCE(AppByENo6,AppByENo5,AppByENo4,AppByENo3,AppByENo2,AppByENo1)
    as 'ApprovedBy',
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RN
    FROM FO_Entry INNER JOIN Employees ON FO_Entry.Hq_Code = Employees.E_HQCode)  as abc
where ApprovedBy LIKE '%2459%'
AND RN>=10 AND RN<=20
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Its working now.  Thanks for fixing the issue.

Comment: Welcome If you got your answer please accept and upvote @Sixthsense

Comment: Actually someone is down voted your post.  So it shown -10.  I upvoted it so now its showing as 0.  Regarding marking as answer SO saying that I have to wait 9 minutes.  I will do it once the timer elapse.

Answer (score 1):

To select row 11 to 20, use fetch `offset` to skip 10 rows, and then `fetch first` to select the following 10 rows:

```
select
...
ORDER BY somecolumn
OFFSET 10 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Getting this error****Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FETCH'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Invalid usage of the option FIRST in the FETCH statement.*** SQL Line---select Rec_Num from MyTable
order by Rec_Num
OFFSET 10 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY---

Comment: @Sixthsense, which SQL Server version are you using? A reasonable new version is needed.

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: @Sixthsense, Perhaps SQL Server wants `OFFSET 10 FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY` here?